# Froogaloop eventlistener get_duration issue

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api, froogaloop

I have a weird problem, im trying to develop my own learning site and i have made a script that shows text notes along side the video. The issue is that the listener shows the wrong section of text at random times. This only happens in IE and chrome, there is no problem in firefox

Link: http://instantchange.no/hold-balance-i-dit-liv-ledere/

(Watch at 8:45, it will skip to a previous string of text)

The JS code is as following

```js
var texts = {
  20000: "<b>3-deling</b>",
  27000: "<b>”Der er jo aldrig plads til mig”</b> </br> 3-deling",
  48000: "<b>Jo, der ER plads til dig i dit liv</b> </br> ”Der er jo aldrig plads til mig” </br> 3-deling",
  70000: "<b>Timer på job/studie/andet</b>",
  80000: "<b>Faglitteratur,</b> Timer på job/studie/andet",
  82000: "<b>Netværksmøder,</b> Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  84000: "<b>Messer,</b> Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  112000: "<b>Dem der kommer tæt på,</b>Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  130000: "<b>Sundhed,</b> Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  135000: "<b>Kæresteliv,</b> Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  137000: "<b>Børn, forældre,</b> Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  145000: "<b>Dig selv,</b> Børn, forældre, Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  147000: "<b>Søvn,</b> Dig selv, Børn, forældre, Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  150000: "<b>Kost,</b> Søvn, Dig selv, Børn, forældre, Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  180000: "<b>Kusiner/fætre,</b> Kost, Søvn, Dig selv, Børn, forældre, Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  185000: "<b>Foreninger,</b> Kusiner/fætre, Kost, Søvn, Dig selv, Børn, forældre, Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  190000: "<b>Naboer,</b> Foreninger, Kusiner/fætre, Kost, Søvn, Dig selv, Børn, forældre, Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  215000: "<b>Skille P og S,</b> Naboer, Foreninger, Kusiner/fætre, Kost, Søvn, Dig selv, Børn, forældre, Kæresteliv, Sundhed, Dem der kommer tæt på, Messer, Netværksmøder, Faglitteratur, Timer på job/studie/andet",
  270000: "<b>Tegn ”lige her og nu”</b>",
  525000: "<b>Ja! ... Tillykke!</b>",
  532000: "<b>Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning</b> </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  350000: "<b>Tegn det, du gerne vil have</b> </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  395000: "<b>Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde?</b> </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  420000: "<b>Det kan være svært at vælge fra</b> </br> Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde? </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  505000: "<b>Vægtningen er ok, men indholdet skal forandres</b> </br> Det kan være svært at vælge fra </br> Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde? </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  530000: "<b>Giver mennesker og aktiviteter mig det, som jeg ønsker?</b> </br> Vægtningen er ok, men indholdet skal forandres </br> Det kan være svært at vælge fra </br> Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde? </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  540000: "<b>Bidrager mennesker og aktiviteter positivt?</b> </br> Giver mennesker og aktiviteter mig det, som jeg ønsker? </br> Vægtningen er ok, men indholdet skal forandres </br> Det kan være svært at vælge fra </br> Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde? </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  595000: "<b>Hvad er det vigtigste i mit arbejdsliv overhovedet?</b> </br> Bidrager mennesker og aktiviteter positivt? </br> Giver mennesker og aktiviteter mig det, som jeg ønsker? </br> Vægtningen er ok, men indholdet skal forandres </br> Det kan være svært at vælge fra </br> Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde? </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  625000: "<b>Hvad vil du undre ingen omstændigheder undvære?</b> </br> Hvad er det vigtigste i mit arbejdsliv overhovedet? </br> Bidrager mennesker og aktiviteter positivt? </br> Giver mennesker og aktiviteter mig det, som jeg ønsker? </br> Vægtningen er ok, men indholdet skal forandres </br> Det kan være svært at vælge fra </br> Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde? </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  640000: "<b>Samme spørgsmål for P og S</b> </br> Hvad vil du undre ingen omstændigheder undvære? </br> Hvad er det vigtigste i mit arbejdsliv overhovedet? </br> Bidrager mennesker og aktiviteter positivt? </br> Giver mennesker og aktiviteter mig det, som jeg ønsker? </br> Vægtningen er ok, men indholdet skal forandres </br> Det kan være svært at vælge fra </br> Hvad skal de enkelte elementer indeholde? </br> Tegn det, du gerne vil have </br> Nej! ... tegn så din ønskede vægtning </br> Ja! ... Tillykke!",
  665000: "<b>Balancen skifter hele tiden </b>",
  735000: "<b>Forebygger stress!</b> </br> Balancen skifter hele tiden",
  773000: "<b>Dele arbejdslivet op</b>",
  833000: "<b>Hvilke opgaver er der i min ledergerning? </b> </br> Dele arbejdslivet op",
  843000: "<b>Hvad er det for driftsopgaver, jeg har/løser?</b> </br> Hvilke opgaver er der i min ledergerning? </br> Dele arbejdslivet op",
  898000: "<b>Balancetjek ved medarbejderudviklingssamtaler?</b> </br> Hvad er det for driftsopgaver, jeg har/løser? </br> Hvilke opgaver er der i min ledergerning? </br> Dele arbejdslivet op"
};

var jqTextBox;

var updateText = function(seconds) {
  var milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
  var newText = "";
  for (var index in texts) {
    if (index < milliseconds) {
      newText = texts[index];
    }
  }
  jqTextBox.html(newText);
};

function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
  updateText(data.seconds);
}

$(function() {
  jqTextBox = $('#txtBox');
  var player = $f($('.change')[0]);

  // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
  player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
  });

  var status = $('.status');

  // Call the API when a button is pressed
  $('button').bind('click', function() {
    player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

```html
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item change" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/129963611?color=f87710&amp;title=0&api=1" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<span id="txtBox" class="handwriting"></span>
```

If you have any idea what is happening, plz let me know

Comment: Just having a quick glance, I can see you're missing the occasional closing </b> tag. I'm doubtful that it would cause your bug, but best to eliminate any obvious issues.

Comment: Ahh yeah, Thanks for the glance atleast :) Updated it to fix the closing </b> tags

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer

1) I messed up the order of which the array was ordered

2) Firefox loaded the objects different than Chrome and IE

Works like a charm now!